PayPal checkout integration with IIS WebForms application
I have a WebForms application running on IIS at port 80.
I have a PayPal button on the Checkout.aspx page. This button uses javascript to call the CreateOrder function in the same machine server-side javascript Node.js app running on port 8888.
The problem is that the client javascript is not able to communicate with the nodejs server.
I've searched the web and all I found is create a IIS Reverse Proxy mechanism. But that's for the entire site, so any user request on my site will be routed to Nodejs; and that's not what I want. I only want that button to call Nodejs. So how do I make that happen? Much appreciate any suggestion.
I've searched the web and all I found is create a IIS Reverse Proxy mechanism. But that's for the entire site, so any user request on my site will be routed to Nodejs; and that's not what I want. I only want that button to call Nodejs.


But that's for the entire site, so any user request on my site will be routed to Nodejs; and that's not what I want. I only want that button to call Nodejs.

As far as I know, this should work for you. In the case you mentioned, you may have configured something like this (match rule): <match url="(.*)" />, which causes all requests to be routed to the Node.js server.
What you need to consider is how to correctly set the matching rules for the request, by filtering the request so that specific requests are routed to the Node.js server instead of all requests.
For example, this button request to: /api/CreateOrder, in this case, you can set the match rule: <match url="^api/CreateOrder$" />. The whole rewrite rule might look like this:
<rule name="ProxyNodeJsRequest" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^api/createorder$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8888{R:0}" />
</rule>


Sorry I didn't mention that I'm not using IISNode, I'm using HttpPlatformHandler. IISNode was throwing errors, but HttpPlatformHandler went through smoothly. So, is there a way to do the same type of filter?

What error did it throw? Have you add conditions configuration to ensures that only requested paths that are neither files nor directories are rewritten to the Node.js application. Something like this:  <conditions>   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> </conditions>

I followed instructions from this article: https://salvatore.netlify.app/2020/11/08/hosting-node-js-apps-in-iis-on-windows/
That worked fine inside the server by typing: localhost/helloexpress. But to access from outside the server, I have to create a IIS binding: devserv.helloexpress.com
And when I type that url in client browser, I get "404 - File or directory not found". No errors thrown by using httppPlatformHandler instead. (https://eysermans.com/post/using-http-platform-handler-to-host-a-node-js-application-via-iis/).

Use failed request tracing to obtain relevant log analysis, which will help locate the problem.

I'm giving up using Node.js for PayPal integration. I found a very simple client-only javascript that does all the job:  "createOrder: function (data, actions) { return actions.order.create({.......})", instead of the call to server Node.js:  "const response = await fetch("/api/orders", {
method: "POST",........}" . This client javascript is not documented in any PayPal document. I could only find in stackoverflow posts and other forums.

Glad your issue was resolved.
